# Android Studio does not allow user input (neither physical keyboard or virtual keyboard)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a simple android application calculator. Basically you enter two number from EditText and sum the result form TextView. However, When I run the application from emulator, I cannot enter the number in the EditText field by keyboard and there is no virtual keyboard show up.

This is my content_main.xml XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="edu.ohiostate.sum.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:background="#ffffff">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sum"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Result"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Number 1"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:hint="Number 2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="Test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In your emulator settings there is a setting which says `Hardware keyboard present`, is this checked? If so you must uncheck it.